# How should I start worldbuiliding?

Tags: worldbuilding-process, worldbuilding-resources

I know a little digital art. I can write and I am a science enthusiast who knows quite a lot about science.

What are the to-go tips for a beginner at world building? How should I start? What are some generally accepted do's and don't?

Comment: While I like the question I feel this is likely to end up closed as too broad or opinion based. Can you narrow it down a little to a more specific element of the process you are struggling with?

Comment: Isn't this actually a question for Writers.SE? It seems you are asking about writing, not actually about world building as prescribed on the [On Topic page](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) of the Help Center.

Comment: If you an enthusiast, consider creating an account on the site. This way its easier to interact with the community.

Comment: Maybe this question is suitable for meta WB

Answer (score 3):

Start with genre, proceed to type and then work on details and ask for help. This is just my opinion others will tell you different things are important to getting started but here's my take for what it's worth.

Genre, are you building a fantasy world, or is it a modern adventure or period piece where you're building/rebuilding a few city blocks or is this a science-fiction universe. This answers a lot of the groundwork questions around the scope of the build and starting technology and the existence of magic etc...

Type, are you telling a story in novel form and you want the underpinnings or are you building a world for RPGs, this gives you some idea of how much of the world you need to fill in, novels only need worlds that cover the content of the story while RPGs need *as much information as possible* because PCs don't stay on story.

Having completed these basics you should then start to see areas of detail work that you can do and areas you need help with, that's when you come here.

Somewhere around here is a set of steps or something for a complete Worldbuilding process case study but I can't find it.

Answer (score 2):

There are two ways to look at this.

For things like "hard" science Fiction, make an assumption, and use world building to track the idea through to its logical conclusions. Look for second and third order effects. As the late [Jerry Pournelle](https://infogalactic.com/info/Jerry_Pournelle) liked to point out, people had predicted the automobile for centuries, but *no one* ever predicted strip malls, drive in movie theatres, rush hour traffic or how cars would affect dating, courtship and sex.

If your invention of the [atomic hyperspatial frappe mixer](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ac7G7xOG2Ag) can cause interesting second and third order effects on society, then you can look at these effects as being the basis to set or write interesting stories about how these effects affect the people in universe. OTOH if the atomic hyperspatial frappe mixer only makes Starbucks 10% more expensive, then aside from modifying the duties of the baristas, there is little to write about there.

For fantasy, the story idea is probably already there, so the primary purpose of worldbuilding is to provide a setting and a mental and physical map for the action to take place. If Gondor is several hundred miles from where the action is currently taking place, can your heroes get there in time for the action to logically take place, or will they  never arrive in time to influence the action (in which case you need to revise the plot, move the characters or create a new storyline which can eventually tie in the action in the other location). In this case, it should be a guide to prevent giant plot holes from consuming your story.

One side opinion which I read many years ago is [J.R.R Tolkien](https://infogalactic.com/info/J._R._R._Tolkien) had created [Eä](https://infogalactic.com/info/Cosmology_of_Tolkien%27s_legendarium#E.C3.A4) over a period of decades, and LOTR, the Silmarillion and other tales were not "fantasy" at all in the sense we understand, but histories of a fully fleshed out, but totally imaginary realm. This is a bit closer to the use of worldbuilding in hard SF, but unless you are a master of the level of J.R.R Tolkien, and are willing to put decades into the process, I'd probably not recommend it.

Answer (score 1):

Come up with a good story, then construct a *self-consistent* setting where it can happen. There are a few writers who can get away with bad stories in great worlds, but usually a bad story will ruin the experience for the reader.

From the story, come up with conditions for the setting. For example:

- Do you need instant communications? That means one world, or FTL communications. And if you want to *avoid* instant communications, what is the reason? Simply distance and the lack of FTL?
- Do you have interstellar travel? How fast and how expensive? If emigration puts a dent into the Earth population, it must be remarkably fast and cheap.
- Are there human/alien crossbreeds? If so, will you gloss over how it happened, or do you have an *elaborate* explanation how such a thing can be?

Answer (score 1):

Decide what you are building a world for, is it for a game, a story, shits and giggles. This will decide a lot about what you want out of the world.

then pick your scale, is this one world, one world of many, one small area of a bigger planet, a constructed world, etc.

After that the options quickly multiply, making it impossible to go forward without knowing more, but this is how you start.

Answer (score 0):

As a writer I think it's best to start with, as has been mentioned before, a story. Once you have a series of events you wish to happen, you then need to have these events unfold somehow. The most obvious way to do this, is to have characters interacting with each other and the world they inhabit. Figure out what each of your characters would require to achieve the events of your story, then build a world around which these requirements are achievable in a way that shows both consistency within the worlds functioning laws of existence, and in a manner that can show some personal growth for your characters.

Once you have done this you have some choices to make.

Do you wish to create a back story explaining the creation of said world such as JRR Tolkiens’ History of Middle Earth, or do you proceed under the assumption people will figure out everything they need to know from the characters actions?

Do you want to make the world the characters live in a very large part of the story, such as almost any off world science fiction story, where the very existence or survival of the characters may depend on the parameters of the world - Or is it more low key and basically a version of some historical era of earth such as Game of Thrones, where some magical bits are added but generally functions like earth?

What time period, or periods if it involves time travel, in which do you wish the world to exist? This is where consistency is key. Regardless of the time period the characters or story are in, you must be true to that times' parameters. If you set the requirement that it’s an advanced space level civilization, and you want to incorporate medieval elements, you must be careful how you explain the existence of that mix of time specific elements.

Once you have answered these questions, you start explaining in detail the specific paths through the world your characters must take to achieve the goals you’ve set for them. As you bring them from a room in a castle to the streets of the city, you must flesh out that world as the characters would see it, all while keeping consistent with the time period and laws of that world. As you move through the journey your characters take, you will have to expand or explain the world they live in to create realism for the reader. If you follow these basic steps you should be able to build any world you wish.